How to dynamically render viewport at low resolution in Inkscape?
This question is similar to How to achieve a pixelated view for low resolution graphics in Inkscape? in that it requests a way to automatically convert a graphic into a low-resolution form, but differs in that I would like to apply this effect dynamically to the viewport, rather than have to design in my display's native resolution and then export to a lower resolution.
The iconographic design panel might appear to be a solution, but it solely supports a few preset resolutions (rather than permitted arbitrary values) and its rendering size cannot change - it's stuck as a small box.
I ask this because I create all of my designs in Inkscape, before I apply any transformations (in GIMP) because I need to create designs which look good as vectors. Pixelation is secondary, but still almost as important.

Hi. Do you know that you can import SVGs (or just click and drag them) directly into GIMP, and set the resolution when importing?  So there's no need to export from Inkscape as raster first.   There's no way I know of to do what you want in Inkscape. It's vector based, nothing to do with pixels really.  Inkscape has no resolution as such. There is no pixel preview, except for the icon preview you already mentioned.

Another possibility would be to use Krita (a raster image editor) which has support for File Layers.  You can basically click and drag an SVG into Krita, use the option to create a New File Layer, and when you alter the Vector file in Inkscape, it will update automatically in the Krita document.  To scale File Layers in Krita, you need to add a Transform Mask to the layer

@BillyKerr, importing it into GIMP wouldn't be a solution, because it wouldn't automatically update as I apply changes. I need a preview. However, that idea with Krita sounds brilliant. I'll definitely try it! I'd accept that as an answer (even though technically it's not) if you're willing to post it as one.

@BillyKerr, I've just tested that in Krita. Indeed, it's real-time, so that's almost exactly what I want. Many, many thanks. However, do you know how to import multiple artboards of the SVG? It solely imports the first for me.

Multiple artboards are an Inkscape thing, rather than an SVG thing.  I don't think Krita supports them. Just the simplest of SVGs really. I would keep each as a separate file.

I've thought about this a bit more, and actually there is a way to do this entirely in Inkscape. It's not obvious, and requires a bit of set up. I've added an answer now. This won't solve your multiple artboard issue however. You would need to keep each artboard as a separate file.

Inkscape currently has no pixel preview mode, except for the icon preview you have already mentioned. However, another document can be used to preview a single art board at a lower resolution using various tools. Here are two possible options:
Inkscape
Inkscape can link to external SVGs and display them as rendered pixel images. To set it up, make sure you have saved your SVG first, then:

Create a new blank document.

Select File > Import.

Choose the SVG you want to import, and when the SVG Input dialog comes up change the settings as shown here, choose the Linked SVG option, and set the DPI to what you want, and select the Blocky rendering option:


Now, if you edit the original SVG in Inkscape and save it, then return to the document with the imported linked SVG, the raster image will update automatically within a second or two.


Here's a demonstration. The original vector is on the right, the raster pixelated preview is on the left.
Click to see larger
Krita
Krita (a raster image editor) has support for File Layers. This is a feature which allows linked files in a Krita document. You can basically click and drag an SVG into a blank Krita document, then select the option to create a New File Layer, and when you alter the original vector file and save it in Inkscape, it will update automatically in the Krita document. Note: to scale File Layers in Krita, you need to add a Transform Mask to the layer.
